# Probability: Given fair coin tossed 2n times, what is the probability of getting n heads?

Tags: probability

This problem is 17.1 on probability from MIT Mathematics for Computer Science.

Let B be the number of heads that come up on 2n independent tosses of a fair coin. Pr[B = n] is asymptotically equal to one of the expressions given below.

1. $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi n}}$
2. $\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$
3. $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$
4. $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi n}}$

### Approach

Since the outcome probabilities are uniform we should be able to use the formula:

$P[B = n] = \frac{\text{number of ways to get n heads}}{\text{number of outcomes}}$

To find the number of ways to get n heads we can imagine a bit string where a 0 is tails and a 1 is heads. So the number of ways to get n heads is:

$2n\choose{n}$

The number of outcomes is the number of different combinations we could get from the coin tosses, so:

$2^{2n}$

Therefore:

$P[B = n] = \frac{2n\choose{n}}{2^{2n}}$

However, I'm not sure how this relates to the options given.

**Update:** Thanks to commenter it is likely that the approach is along the right lines however I need to look up Stirling's approximation. From a brief check that looks like it will work. Thank you!

Comment: Expand the binomial and use stirlings approximation